# Is it possible to launch an iOS app using Universal Links (deep link) from Email - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Is there a way to launch my iOS app using Universal Links from the Email (on Safari) ?

I have an iOS app containing the forgot password process, that's why I need to redirect the user from email to my app.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you open the link from, if there is an app that can handle the URL you should be prompted to open in the app

Comment: Just register a URL schema. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app). Read the *important* section at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES.

In order to do that you have 2 options :

1 - Using `deeplink`:

You can add a custom scheme to your app ( like `com.yourcompany.yourapp://` ) and use this scheme in your email to open your app ( is it is installed )

->  com.yourcompany.yourapp://forgottentPassword/token

**+** Super easy to implement. No server side configuration

**-** If the app is not installed or if the user is not an an iPhone it will not work.

2 - Using `Universal Links`:
See https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/ for more details.

You can *pair* your app with a website. Every time an app ( except safari ) will try to open a link from your website ( ie: `https://youdomain.com/forgotPassword?token=1234` ) your app will be awake and asked if the user may continue using your app.

**+** Even if the user don't have the app, or if the reset password occurs on a desktop everything will be ok for your user.

**-** You will need to access to your webserver to add a configuration file ( to ensure you are the owner of the website, and to declare all URLs you want to support )

**Conclusion**: You can and based on my experience, you should support Universal Links

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can open your iOS Application from anywhere except Skype. and if you want to create dynamic link with firebase. you can refere https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create this link.

Comment: Thanks Dixit, at the moment I'm not working with firebase !